# "A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again" in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to Place order in magento 2. when i click on Place order I am facing This error "A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again.".

My payment method is Cash On Delivery.

in Console "{"message":"A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again.","trace":"#0 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(15, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#1 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(15, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#3 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array)\n#4 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(15, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#5 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#6 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))\n#7 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#8 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#9 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#10 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#11 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(137): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#12 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#13 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#14 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#15 {main}"}"

Please Help

Comment: That's a generic error that means you got an error 400/500 from the attempt to submit payment information. It requires the correct JSON to be submitted. It can be caused by a number of things so you need to find the content of the XHR request that is sending the information to it and then check if something custom you have done on the checkout is breaking, the php function or one that's being called before it returns the error. Commonly this can happen with customer/customer address attributes and messing around with advanced js bundling.

Comment: several users posted their solutions. you may find it helpful. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149546/magento-2-an-error-occurred-on-the-server-please-try-to-place-the-order-again

Comment: Thank you for reply but I got the answer.

Comment: @VishalVarshney I am also facing the same problem would you please tell me how can you resolve that?

Comment: @VishalVarshney if you found the solution, why didn't you post it here?

Comment: Did anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but when I checked log error Message, I found the three tables sequence_order, sequence_shipment and sequence_invoice were missing also need to add this table entries in sales_sequence_profile and sales_sequence_meta table.

I found this is useful https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110701/magento-2-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1103-incorrect-table-name-query

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because i forgot to start rabbitMQ server which was necessary for one of my modules.
I was able to find it by debugging the actual error by changing the error display **"A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again."** to **$e->getMessage()** which showed actual error message as **"connection refused on localhost:127.0.0.1:5672"** (5672 is port no for rabbitMQ) in **module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.**

Note: Ensure all your services are running

Answer (score -1):

The same error is facing by me today. In my case i have added an observer for sending data in ERP. There was some error while placing order.

So i suggest you please disable recently added module or disable observer or plugins. then try and debug your code. it would defiantly solve and help full.